# Create and write an excel file on server using phpexcel?

Tags: php, excel, file, url-rewriting

How i can create a excel file `.xlsx` into a folder like `'/temp'` , like the creation of text file, than i want to use this file after open to write data into it using PHP, it's that possible??? using `phpexcel` library? The second question is how proceed to write data into cell in a excel file automatic format? how  proceed to save data into this file destination??? how to use `::load()` instead of new creation?
Can be existed some instruction to writer in phpexcel instead pf reader like this:

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("05featuredemo.xlsx");
```

-->

```
$objReader = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007();
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("05featuredemo.xlsx");
```

To write directly into existing excel file (safe memory and time)...

Comment: would a .csv file work for you? you wouldn't have any formatting but you would be able to input all of your data

Comment: You create a PHPExcel object, write the data to that object, instantiate the Excel2007 Writer and use that to save the file to the directory and filename of your choice... there are dozens of examples showing how to do this in the PHPExcel documentation

Comment: @Mike , with a csv file, not possible to encode an arabic data , may that be a problem...

Comment: @MarkBaker so i cannot write directly to excel file instead of writing in memory than save it with output excel???? i do this concept because i discover something good, when i write directly to a text file for example, (open and write) that's gain time and memory than write data and save the header with output text...

Comment: @MarkBaker i edit the question for some explication, u can see it please.

Answer (score 0):

No! There is no such creature! You can't edit an Excel file without loading it first using any tool or library of which I'm aware (not even MS Excel itself). PHPExcel is no exception: you load the file into memory (cell caching reduces the memory requirements), you set cell values as you need, you save the file. All of this is fully documented, with a lot of example code demonstrating how it is done.

If you really wanted to write something yourself that would edit the file "in situ", without using any memory and incredibly quickly, then the structure of OfficeOpenXML (xlsx) files is fully documented and available for [public download](http://www.ecma-international.org/news/TC45_current_work/TC45_available_docs.htm) from ECMA.

The .xlsx file would need to be unzipped, which created a collection of XML files spread across several folders. You can then write a script that edits those XML files individually, adding whatever you need. Then you rezips the folders and files to recreate the .xlsx file. Clearly you're an experienced coder, so you shouldn't find this too difficult now I've pointed you to the documents detailing the OfficeOpenXML structure.

Alternatively, use wrappers such as COM or PUNO that allow you to call Excel COM or Open/Libre Office directly to load, manipulate the data as you need, and then save... but even these will still load the workbook before allowing you to manipulate it.

Comment: thank u so match for your suggestion, i will try to use the OfficeOpenXML structure...

Comment: Kindlyl one question clarified, can i convert a text file to excel file using php?with the basic format and text into cells?tab delimiter?i.e there is one text file exported in some folder(./temp),let's say, test.txt, can i convert deirectly test.txt to test.xls into the same destination (./temp)?using php/mysql?

Comment: As long as that text file has some form of structure that you can parse to extract text... but it won't be a direct conversion (that's why libraries like PHPExcel exist)... and do you want Excel BIFF (xls) or OfficeOpenXML (xlsx)?

Comment: Mr.Mark Baker,how i can do the delimiter of cells contents ("") for best view into text file or excel file???some text appears in separated cells may be because contents ("") characters

Comment: In a CSV File, " is escaped as ""

Comment: If a string contains a delimiter then that string must be enclosed in quotes " -- this is all standard CSV formatting. The traditional delimiter is the comma (that's what CSV or Comma-separated value means) but can be any character... tab or pipe (|) are also sometimes used

Comment: kindly, how i can use the cashing cells in phpexcel library?which instructions are permitted for that? using cashe in cells for the performance action export?

Comment: Kindly, this is the message appeared when i try to export a big data : [Bad Request-

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand].Can you understand what's happening? memory issue? or disk?or something else?

Comment: Mr.MarkBaker, also how i can use these parameters:cache_to_discISAM, cache_to_phpTemp, and cache_to_memcache for the optimization of code?Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a whole lot easier if your read the developer documentation: the relevant section is 4.2.1 entitled "Cell Caching"

Comment: yes thank you i have checked it, i just asked to know if another thing or documentation exist for this case...

Comment: But why something, the message below appears:[Bad Request- Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand]?any suggestion?

Comment: Mr.MarkBaker, can i use more than one method of cashe cells?i.e casge_in_memory and cache_to_phpTemp?

Comment: You can use more than one method, but only one method per workbook. If you instantiate/load more than one PHPExcel object, then each can use a different cache

Comment: thank you. Can i use more PHPExcel object for one Excel sheet output?if yes, than please notify me which instructions can be done.

Comment: Each PHPExcel object represents a workbook, a workbook comprises one or more PHPExcel_WorkSheet objects, each of which represents a worksheet in that workbook

Comment: No it isn't typical, the vast majority of developers are only working with a single workbook at a time, only a very few use more than one

Comment: Ok Mr. Mark Baker, Thank you so match.